# Python Requests: Handling Exceptions and Ensuring Server Response

Tags: python, exception, python-requests, timeout, httprequest

I'm developing a Python script using the requests library for HTTP requests. I need guidance on handling potential exceptions gracefully and ensuring that I receive a response from the server. Currently, I'm encountering issues with exceptions or no response in terminal.

[Here's the current code snippet I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zsWV.png)

I've implemented a code snippet that sends a GET request to a specific URL with headers and payload. I've tried using a try-except block to catch any exceptions, but I'm still facing problems with handling exceptions and empty terminal

Comment: Please format your code as part of your question and not as a linked image